# Is it possible for TCP can accept out of order segments?

Tags: ipv4, tcp, ipv6, ip-address, transport-protocol

TCP is connection-oriented protocol whereas IP isn't connection-oriented protocol. Any packets before sending into transport layer sorted operation must have been done in network layer. That's why we get in-order packets in transport layer by TCP. Whenever in TCP flow control   is some packets could be loss and there is a chance of out of order delivery. But always we get the in-order acknowledgement. My question is that packets lost is the only reason of connectionless of TCP?
I'm struggling to understand this concept.

Comment: if would be appreciated if you could proof read your question. you have sentences like transport layer and transport layer and they do not make sense.

Comment: It's hard to understand your question. But basically TCP provides a guarantee that the data get delivered in order to the application. It is impossible to provide this guarantee if packets are permanently lost. It though possible that packets arrive in different order or duplicates since TCP can resolve these problems by eliminating duplicates and by reordering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still do not understand the question fully and thus point out where misconception comes from. But, does this clarify things?

[image]

Note, that TCP is stream based, i.e., on the sender side (left) upper layer passes the stream of bytes which TCP divides into packets. on the receiver TCP reassembles the stream from packets and passes bytes to the upper layer.

I will try to consider the question one line at a time.:

> TCP is connection-oriented protocol whereas IP isn't
> connection-oriented protocol.

Connection oriented and reliable.

> Any packets before sending into
> transport layer sorted operation must have been done in network layer.

No, sorted operation is done in transport layer, by TCP.

> That's why we get in order packets in transport layer by TCP.

Again, packets do not get in order when entering transport layer, transport layer puts them in order. They get in order when leaving transport layer and entering upper layer.

> Whenever
> in TCP flow control

Flow control or congestion control?

> is some packets could be loss and there is a
> chance of out order delivery. But always we get the in order
> acknowledgement.

TCP always acknowledge the last packet received in order. If a packet is received out of order, TCP sends an acknowledgement where acknowledgement number is the number corresponds to the last in-order received packet.

In other words this does not refer to what happens, that refers to what TCP writes in the acknowledgement number field.

> My question is that packets lost is the only reason
> of connectionless of TCP?

Connectionless? please correct?

No, packets can be reordered in the network.  A classical example: in a packet switched network packets can follow different paths (which take differently long). They will arrive in different order.

TCP congestion control will act, in this case erroneously. Because it is impossible to distinguish between these cases before all packets arrive, and TCP congestion control will go on the side of caution and assume the loss.

> I'm struggling to understand this concept.

Comment: TCP connection-oriented means not accept any out of order delivery... But reassembles against connection-oriented.

Comment: TCP does accept out of order delivery. TCP is reliable means that the layer above TCP does not accept out of order delivery. IP is unreliable means that the layer above it must accept out of order delivery.

Comment: Different website, different people saying different answer... Some are saying that your answer.. And some are saying  that my question.. That's why I posted this.. Don't know what is right..

Comment: if you have sources - add them to your question. But generally there is a difference between what layer does (functionality) and how it appears to upper layers (interface). And this question is exactly about the difference between these two.

Comment: Connection-oriented means we directly got in order packets no need reorder..

Comment: 1) source of information please! 2) on a separate note - connection oriented means that there is a connection state.  reliable means (among others) that packets are delivered in order. You can be connection oriented and not reliable.

Comment: One thing tell in network layer we also get out of order delivery but not doing sorting, it's also connectionless. But in transport layer we accept out of order delivery but doing sorting, it's connection-oriented.

Comment: " TCP is reliable means that the layer above TCP does not accept out of order delivery." It' seems to be wrong statement. Reliable means retransmission during failure..

Comment: yes, TCP does that, so that upper layer protocol does not have to.

Comment: "TCP congestion control will act , in this case erroneously "---- why TCP  congestion control will act erroneously? What do you want to mean by this sentence?

Comment: @AlokMaity because it will treat reordering as loss, although there was no actual packet lost

Comment: how can you say reordering as loss? And how TCP works erroneously?

Comment: what do you mean "reordering as loss"?

Comment: @AlokMaity tcp assumes loss after receiving a certain amount (dupack treshold) of duplicate ACKs. By default it starts with 3. When segments arrive out of order, dupacks are generated. If enough segments arrive out of order, enough dupacks will be generated, and sender needs to assume packet loss and trigger congestion response. Since packets were only reordered, and not lost, this congestion response is not necessary. Usually, in modern TCP implementations this can be detected and dupack treshold is raised.

Comment: "Since packets were only reordered, and not lost "--- it's not understood?

Comment: if the packet eventually arrives, it was not lost; dupack mechanism cannot distingush between those cases

Comment: data link layer to network layer in receiver side out of order is possible if I send packet in order packet in data link layer? I mean travelling from switch to router in receiver side out of order is possible if I send packet in order packet in data link layer?

Comment: @AlokMaity there is no guarantee that reordering cannot happen. this means you cannot build protocols that assue that reordering does not happen. whether it can actually happen depends on too many factors and there is no answer for every combination.

Answer (score 1):

> TCP is connection-oriented protocol whereas IP isn't connection-oriented protocol.

Correct.

> Any packets before sending into transport layer sorted operation must have been done in network layer.

The transport layer can't get its datagrams/segments anywhere by itself. It requires the routing service done in the network layer.

The *re-sorting* of out-of-order segments for those transport-layer protocols like TCP that provide in-order delivery for the upper application layer is up to the transport-layer protocol itself.

> That's why we get in order packets in transport layer by TCP. Whenever in TCP flow control is some packets could be loss and there is a chance of out order delivery. But always we get the in order acknowledgement.

*Selective acknowledgement* in TCP can also provide out-of-order acknowledgement. The various algorithms treat this differently though in order to avoid performance problems.

> My question is that packets lost is the only reason of connectionless of TCP?

TCP is *always* connection-oriented and stateful. It provides reliable, in-order, arbitrary-length transport, necessitating the tracking of connection states - it'd be very hard to impossible to achieve TCP's functionality in a stateless model.

For a common connection-less and stateless transport protocol, take a look at UDP. IP itself in the network layer is also connectionless and stateless.

Comment: TCP is Connection-oriented means we directly got in order packets no need of reordering?

Comment: TCP provides in-order transport for the application above, but since the underlying network layer does *not* provide in-order transport it needs to buffer and re-sort data segments where required. The requirement for socket *states* comes from that buffering (together with transport reliability).

Comment: In the sense if I sorting all the packets in network layer, it seems to be connection-oriented... My question basis on reordering connection-oriented or less depends?

Comment: A connection-less transport protocol can only do so much. Just try to create a concept for in-order, reliable and arbitrary-length transport without using connection states and you'll see the benefit.

Comment: You one thing clarify me.. In L3 it's not doing sorting it's connectionless and in L4 it's doing sorting means Connection-oriented?

Comment: IP is generally connectionless and doesn't provide in-order delivery, so it may cause out-of-order delivery introduced by packet switching. TCP is connection-oriented and provides in-order delivery as well (plus other features). Other L3 or L4 protocols may do things differently.

Comment: Still confusing me.. In TCP we are getting out of order delivery.. But we're doing explicitly sorting making as in order not implicitly getting in order.. So how is it Connection-oriented?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129392/discussion-between-zac67-and-alok-maity).

Comment: @Zac67, this is so complicated... everyone says that IP is best-effort TCP is reliable, everyone explains how it achieves this, but there is like no normal explanation of OSI which explains what service (delivery) model really mean :D

Comment: @Alok Maity https://web.mit.edu/Saltzer/www/publications/endtoend/endtoend.pdf this is an explanation why TCP is designed the way it is.

Comment: @Zac67 data link layer to network layer in receiver side out of order is possible if I send packet in order packet in data link layer? I mean travelling from switch to router in receiver side out of order is possible if I send packet in order packet in data link layer?

Comment: Data is always sent in-order by the source but may arrive out-of-order at the destination. The out-of-order data is passed from IP as-is to TCP which then resorts the segment data (using its receive window buffer) and passes it in-order to the application.

Comment: @Zac67 but in receiver side data link layer to network layer out of order possible?

Comment: Yes, that's possible but neither data link layer (e.g. Ethernet) nor network layer (IPv4) care about order, nor do they even notice anything being out of order.